# How do I create an asynchronous/delayed task manager in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know about Active Job -- I'm curious how one can create something like that in Rails? An example would be for a temp directory cleanup daemon (but in the Rails/ruby platform, I don't want a crontab + rake task solution).

I want some behaviour that would be independent of user activity/sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Delayed job: Database based asynchronous priority queue system
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job